# Export HTML page to PDF on user click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

When user click on GeneratePDF button, I need to export the html page into a PDF file. I am successfully exporting HTML page into PDF file but for the first click only I am able to download data into PDF but from the second click I am unable to download the data to PDF file. I am not sure where I went wrong in the code.

Please check the code here:

```js
$(function() {
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.uriit.ru/jsPDF/libs/adler32cs.js/adler32cs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/Blob.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic.js"></script>

<body id="target">
  <div id="content">
    <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>
    <a class="upload">Upload to Imgur</a> 
    <h2>this is <b>bold</b> <span style="color:red">red</span></h2> 
    <p>Feedback form with screenshot This script allows you to create feedback forms which include a screenshot, created on the clients browser, along with the form. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation
      as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page. How does it work? The script is based on the html2canvas library, which renders the current page as a canvas image, by reading the
      DOM and the different styles applied to the elements. This script adds the options for the user to draw elements on top of that image, such as mark points of interest on the image along with the feedback they send. It does not require any rendering
      from the server, as the whole image is created on the clients browser. No plugins, no flash, no interaction needed from the server, just pure JavaScript! Browser compatibility Firefox 3.5+ Newer versions of Google Chrome, Safari & Opera IE9
    </p>

  </div>
  <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript ?

Comment: No i tried with it.. its not working

Comment: I've rolled the question back as you simply incorporated Kristof answer, making the answer lose its meaning. That's not ok, when you have new questions, ask a new one, don't mutate the original question if it already has answers. Thanks!

Comment: hey it is working for you in IE9?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because you define your "doc" variable outside of your click event. The first time you click the button the doc variable contains a new jsPDF object. But when you click for a second time, this variable can't be used in the same way anymore. As it is already defined and used the previous time.

change it to:

```
$(function () {

    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
 $('#cmd').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML(
            $('#target').html(), 15, 15, 
            { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers }, 
            function(){ doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); }
        );

    });  
});
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thank you Kristof Feys, but when I click on the button I can see  2 windows. one is save to PDF window and one more new window is opening with pdf view, How can I remove PDf view in new window...

Comment: Hmmm... when i tested this in jsFiddle i only received the "save to pdf" window. My guess would be that these 2 windows are browser / plugin related...

Comment: Yes, In jsFiddle it is getting only SaveTo PDF  window, but in  Main Application It is getting one more window opened when user click,How can i remove that new window.

Comment: As I am unable to reproduce your issue, i can't really debug it either. You could probably try to remove all your javascript plugins used (except jquery & jspdf) and see if it works then. Afterwards you can re add them one by one to see which one produces the error (if my guess is correct and one of these are producing the issue of course) ... Or if you could reproduce the issue on jsFiddle that could help as well :)

Comment: You can see in this JSFiddle, when we click on "generate button" it shown 2 windows. one is the window to save the PDF file and another new browser is getting opened with PDF view http://jsfiddle.net/y2b7Q/299/

Comment: In Firefox it is displaying the new window, but in Chrome its working perfect, but in Safari and IE its not working

Comment: you could try wrapping it in downloadify (cfr this example: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/downloadify.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40560/discussion-between-user178900-and-kristof-feys)

Comment: @KristofFeys : I worked on above sample and it is not working in IE10. And CSS style is not applied in the PDF. How to get the actual CSS styles in PDF and IE10 issue.

Comment: $(document).ready(function) and $(function) are identical; http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ just says, "If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form."

Comment: what does var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    }; indicates?

Comment: I've used the the solution above but I'm getting a blank PDF file. When I check the console, I'm getting this error `jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!
(anonymous) @ jspdf.debug.js:7747` I am using the jsPDF CDN hosted library What can I do?

Comment: Just generated a blank pdf. I also get the same error as @Mwas

Comment: @djack109 i've updated the code, if you get a blank pdf, you should try to save the document in a callback function (see example)