# Export HTML as PDF via Export Button

Tags: php, html

I have a html document which marks up a report. I have a button on this page "Export as pdf". However I am not sure how to export html into a pdf..Are there any tools out there that anyone recommends for such a task..

Comment: I used to use dom pdf for that, but there are few limitations like css float is not supported. U can have a look at here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: You See This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript).Meet your answer.