# How to read or download generated pdf via ajax with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, download

im creating a service that will transform html to pdf. 
Request with parameter(HTML code to be transfered into PDF) ist send with ajax post.

On server side generating pdf file is no problem.
I was trying to send it back with JSON but i figured out that its not a good idea.
So now im sending it back with no changes - full pdf file as it was generated

```
...
$pdf->Output('out.pdf', 'I');
```

And here comes the tricky part.
What can i do with it on client side?
I was trying to show it or download it but i could not figured out how.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: service_url,
        data: out,
        success: function (data) {
        // WHAT SHOULD I DO WITH "data" IF I WANT TO SHOW IT?
        error: function () {
           alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason this needs to be done with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

a wild guess would say that you need to create a PDFObject and then throw it into the Ajax.

HTML

```
<object id="pdf" data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
  No biggie... you can click here to
  download the PDF file.

```
</object>
```

and in the Ajax you would have to do something like :

```
$.ajax({
    var pdf = $("#pdf");
    type: 'POST',
    url: service_url,
    data: out,
    success: function (data) {
     pdf.show();
    error: function () {
       alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Its not working because "myfile.pdf" does not exist and pdf.show(data) will not reload object.

Comment: then go to this post it explains what you are trying to do:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript