# Convert URL to PDF from the client-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I want to save a web URL as a PDF. For example we can File->Save As-> PDF on the browser to save a webpage as a PDF.

But, in my case when the User provides a URL, I want to convert that URL to a PDF pragmatically.

There are many libraries and SO post on extracting the URL from the backend. According to my requirement I want the PDF to be generated on the Client-Side itself. So the user downloads exactly what he sees.

These are some of the links I visited:

[Export HTML page to PDF on user click using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript)

[Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

**Can someone help me to convert a webpage (given as a URL) to PDF format ?**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is not working with the approaches you have mentioned (and the many more you can get e.g. when Googling `convert url to pdf in browser javascript`)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have tried, but none converts the URL to PDF from the clients Side.